SQL Server Connection Problem While Using Express and Node Js
I have been trying to connect to the SQL Server with node.js. I am using express but I cannot connect to my database.At first I was getting a problem about ISS and I was able to solve it but now the connection is the problem.
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mssql = require("mssql");

// Get request
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    // Config your database credential
    const config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: '12345678',
        server: 'localhost',
        database: 'student'
    };

    // Connect to your database
    mssql.connect(config, function (err) {

        // Create Request object to perform
        // query operation
        let request = new mssql.Request();

        // Query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select * from dbo.student',
            function (err, records) {

                if (err) console.log(err)

                // Send records as a response
                // to browser
                res.send(records);

            });
    });
});

let server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is listening at port 5000...');
});

The Error:

RequestError: No connection is specified for that request.
at Request._query (C:\Users\canbe\OneDrive\Masaüstü\deneme123\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:493:37)
at Request._query (C:\Users\canbe\OneDrive\Masaüstü\deneme123\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:363:11)
at Request.query (C:\Users\canbe\OneDrive\Masaüstü\deneme123\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:429:12)
at C:\Users\canbe\OneDrive\Masaüstü\deneme123\index.js:24:17
at Immediate. (C:\Users\canbe\OneDrive\Masaüstü\deneme123\node_modules\mssql\lib\global-connection.js:56:7)
at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:480:21) {
code: 'ENOCONN'
}

I have tried different implementations for connection but I have failed.

There might be some issue with nested callback though it is a speculation.It is better practice to avoid nested-callback.you better to define the separate module for DB config & DB connection.I hope it will work.
Try this.
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mssql = require("mssql");

const config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: '12345678',
        server: 'localhost',
        database: 'student'
        options : {
           "encrypt": false/true // based on your needs
        }
 }
 // Connect to your database
 mssql.connect(config, function (err) {
   if (err) {
      throw err;
   }
   console.log("Connection Established!");
 });

// Get request
app.get('/', function (req, res) { 

   new mssql.Request().query('select * from dbo.student',(err, records) {

            if (err) {
              console.log(err)
            }else{
            // Send records as a response
            // to browser
              res.send(records);
            }
    });
});

app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is listening at port 5000...');
});

Also you don't need to use let server = to assign port number to your server.Just execute the app.listen(.. code right away.
Also check your query carefully.
